# Form check box not updating state on uncheck

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have form check box where the values of checked boxed are returned as json, if i uncheck the json is still showing the value of the checked value

onChange function

```
const setApproveDeclineValues = (e) => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    setIsChecked({ ...isChecked, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(isChecked);
}
```

Form

```
<Form.Check
    type="checkbox"
    id={data.schudule_number}
    defaultChecked={checked}
    name={data.schudule_number}
    value={data.schudule_number}
    onChange={setApproveDeclineValues}
/>
```

useState

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState({});
```

output when checked

```
{11010: "11010", 11040: "11040"}
```

expected output if unchecked

```
{11010: "11010"}
```

And also how do i update the checked values on useEffect(); ? By defualt all the checkbox are selected, how do i get this values ? i am getting empty json

```
 {}
```

on page load

Comment: It is because `setState` is asynchronous

Comment: what should i use in the case ?

Comment: It is correct to use `useState` but you can't log `isChecked` right after setting it. You can log it inside `useEffect`

Comment: thats fine how about the form unchecked values ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it fully solves it, I mean, works, but it's now scoped for each input. You would need some hight order state to gather this data I guess... But maybe would give some idea.

The pieces of code that looks like `setState(s => !s)` is, what I think its called, a dispatch function. `useState` receives the current state as a argument that you can use, rather than access the state itself (would cause a react warning or a infinite loop. I broke my chrome.)

here's a codesandbox with the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-form-check-box-not-updating-state-on-uncheck-muudh *[edited to handle multiples inputs]*

*ps. I never used `delete` before, not sure how it works, if its safe, etc.*

*(and also pasted for posterity)*

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Checkbox({ name, setChecks }) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (checked) {
      setChecks((c) => ({
        ...c,
        [inputRef.current.name]: inputRef.current.value
      }));
    } else {
      setChecks((c) => {
        const newC = { ...c };
        delete newC[inputRef.current.name]; // but i think that set the value to false may be better. otherwise the problem that you had here may propagate in database or whatever
        return newC;
      });
    }
  }, [checked, setChecks]);

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      type="checkbox"
      defaultChecked={checked} //this could be a prop too
      id={name}
      name={name}
      value={name}
      onChange={() => setChecked((c) => !c)}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [checks, setChecks] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(checks);
  }, [checks]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Checkbox name="one" setChecks={setChecks} />
      <Checkbox name="two" setChecks={setChecks} />
      <Checkbox name="three" setChecks={setChecks} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you could just pass `isChecked` and `setIsChecked` as props and it would work to have an object with a couple of inputs states

Comment: this returns only one object, you have created 3 checkbox

Comment: @DeepakMurthy yeah, as I said, passing the `isChecked` up would solve. Sorry not do it last night, was pretty late here. I edited the code now ;)

Comment: @DeepakMurthy did this solve your problem? If so, please select as accept answer, and if not please give more information about any other problems that you had with that